# Javascript - What's the difference with this object definiton notations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to pass an array to jquery's **.ajax()** function's data parameter. The first approach is that I made my 2-dimensional array like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
      arr[i] = new Array();
  arr[i].lon = "x";
  arr[i].lat = "y";
}
```

Then I try to pass this as **data** in **$.ajax()**:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { vals : arr },
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "namedb.php",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function(data){
      result = data;
      alert(result);
        }
});
```

**test.php** just returns all the values of **$_POST**. So **alert()** here returns:

```
Array
(
)
```

But if I changed the code to:

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
      arr[i] = new Array();
  arr[i] = { lon: "x", lat: "y" };
}
```

the **alert()** returns what I expected:

```
Array
(
    [vals] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lat] => "y",
                    [lon] => "x"
                )
            ...
        )
)
```

I know that both methods initializes the variables/attributes of each element of **arr** (or am I wrong?). But why do the 2 approach behaves differently? (Sorry I could've shorten my question, but I guess I need to explain how I found it).

EDIT: I had added the initialization (arr[i] = new Array();). I must have erased it during the editing of the question. But still the same problem.

Comment: could you add your `test.php` code

Comment: Quoted from the OP, "test.php just returns all the values of $_POST", so that code would be `<?php print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @Thai. yes it's just that simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you did not initialize the array elements.

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
  arr[i] = {}; // initialize it!
  arr[i].lon = "x";
  arr[i].lat = "y";
}
```

Actually, I prefer to write

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
  arr[i] = { lon: "x", lat: "y" };
}
```

Because I don't have to type `arr[i]` 3 times.

---

Using `for in` loops over an array is wrong, you should use `for` loops or jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i ++) {
  arr[i] = { lon: "x", lat: "y" };
}
```

Or

```
var arr = [];
$.each(someArray, function(i, value) {
  arr[i] = { lon: "x", lat: "y" };
});
```

Using [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for adding things to an array is easier, because you don't need to know the next index of an array, also compare with `arr[arr.length]=something`.

```
var arr = [];
$.each(someArray, function(i, value) {
  arr.push({ lon: "x", lat: "y" });
});
```

And now what you're doing is collect data from an array and translate it into another array. jQuery already has a function that does this: [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

```
var arr = $.map(someArray, function(value, i) {
  return { lon: "x", lat: "y" };
});
```

Note that when using `$.each`, the arguments are `i, value`, when you use `$.map`, they are switched.

Comment: A very thorough answer; the OP will probably learn from this :). Especially the point about `for in` loops being bad for arrays. But, keep in mind he was clearly giving us a toy problem; trying to solve it optimally isn't always a great use of your answering time.

Comment: I had edited it and the initialization is originally included. Sorry, I must have erased it during the editing of the question. I had added it now.

Comment: @Jairo, however, you are initializing it as an array, and arrays in JavaScript are for sequential lists, and the contents of an array are the properties with numeric property names, so setting `.x` and `.y` does not modify the contents of an array, and thus, it is still an empty array. You should initialize it as an object instead, by using `new Object()` or `{}`.

Comment: Now I got it! your last comment did the trick. In either approach, as long as I initialize it as **new Object()** instead of **new Array()**, both approach works. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
  arr[i].lon = "x";
  arr[i].lat = "y";
}
```

Gives error. Because arr[i] is always **undefined** for any **i**.

In second case you are creating a new **Object** and assign it to arr[i]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your first approach you are not initializing `arr[i]` to an object before trying to set its properties. Indeed, I think you should be getting JavaScript errors in the debug console. The following would work:

```
var arr = new Array();
for(i in someArray){
  arr[i] = {}; // or "new Object()"
  arr[i].lon = "x";
  arr[i].lat = "y";
}
```

FYI using `new Array()` is bad practice; it's better to use `var arr = []`. Similarly that's why I used `arr[i] = {}` instead of `arr[i] = new Object()`.

**EDIT** In light of your edit, you added the line `arr[i] = new Array()`. Well, arrays don't have `lon` and `lat` properties, so trying to set them will not work! You need to use `arr[i] = new Object()` or (better) `arr[i] = {}`. Only objects get "expando properties," where you just assign things to `myObject.propertyName` and the object suddenly has a `propertyName` property.

Comment: 1) Don't use `for..in` to iterate through Array instances. 2) Concise form: `arr[i] = { lon: "x", lat: "y" };`

Comment: Yes Ates, the OP was already aware of the concise form, given that he showed it to us in the second example and was trying to figure out why his version of the "non-concise" form wasn't working. And yes, `for in` is bad in this toy example, but I assumed his original problem was more complicated and maybe `for in` made sense there.

Comment: sorry. It does have the initialization. I will now edit the question. thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity. Why is `new Array()` or `new Object()` bad practice?? performance??